# Android notifydatasetchanged is not updating?

Tags: android, listview

view does not get updated. Where can i add notifydatasetchanged(); I think this is what i need so the listview gets updated

```
public class UninstallActivity extends Activity {
    private AppAdapter mAppListAdapter = null;
    private EditText mEditText = null;
    private ListView mListView = null;





    public void update() {
        // TODO

        mAppListAdapter.clear();


        Intent aIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        aIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        PackageManager aPackageManager = getPackageManager();
        List <ResolveInfo> aList = aPackageManager.queryIntentActivities(aIntent, PackageManager.GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES);


        for( ResolveInfo rInfo : aList ) {
             if (!isSystemPackage(rInfo)) 
            mAppListAdapter.add(rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo);


            System.out.println("Installed Applications "  +  rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(aPackageManager).toString()); 
        }




        if( mListView != null ) {
            mListView.setAdapter( mAppListAdapter );

           }

    } 






        private boolean isSystemPackage(ResolveInfo ri) {
        return ((ri.activityInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) ? true : false;

        }

    public void remove( ApplicationInfo mApplicationInfo ) {

        Intent aIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, Uri.parse("package:" + mApplicationInfo.packageName));
        startActivity(aIntent);
     }






    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);



        mEditText = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.EditText );
        mEditText.setSingleLine();
        mEditText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
        mEditText.addTextChangedListener( new TextWatcher() {

            @Override 
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if( s.length() > 0 ) {
                    // TODO
                    mAppListAdapter.clear();




                    Intent aIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
                    aIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

                    PackageManager aPackageManager = getPackageManager();
                    List<ResolveInfo>aList = aPackageManager.queryIntentActivities(aIntent, PackageManager.GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES);

                    for( ResolveInfo rInfo : aList ) {

                        String aName = rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel( aPackageManager ).toString().toLowerCase();
                        String aValue = s.toString().toLowerCase();
                        if (!isSystemPackage(rInfo))
                        if( aName.contains( aValue ) ) {
                            mAppListAdapter.add( rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo );

                        }
                    }

                    if( mListView != null ) {
                        mListView.setAdapter(mAppListAdapter);


                    }
                }
                else {
                    UninstallActivity.this.update();

                }
            }




            @Override 
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }
            @Override 
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });

        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        mAppListAdapter = new AppAdapter(this);


        this.update();

        mListView.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override 
            public void onItemClick( AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id ) {
                ApplicationInfo mApplicationInfo = (ApplicationInfo) mAppListAdapter.getItem(position);
                UninstallActivity.this.remove(mApplicationInfo);





            }




        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are never setting the adapter as mlistview is always null from what I see in your code. Plus why would you want to set the adapter again and again?  You should refresh the data and call notifydatasetchanged

Edit : Could not see all the code on the phone , got to see all your code now : Here is what you need to do.

Have an adapterUpdate function in your adapter which takes in your mAppListAdapter as an argument uses it to display the data , basically replace the data the adapter has with what is passed to the adapterUpdate function , once that is done you can call notifyDatasetChanged in the adapter itself to update your listview.

Comment: That's what I am wondering where i set and call notifydatasetchanged?